# Replicate more tables Laravel

Tags: laravel

The next problem is that I have to copy several tables. Now I'm not that familiar with Laravel but I've already tried something. So my function now only copied 1 table. This should be called more:

- lime_groups
- lime_permissions
- Lime_questions etc....

So can someone help me with this?

```
public function copySurvey( Manager $fractal, SurveyTransformer $surveyTransformer ) {
        $copy = Survey::first();

        // copy all atributes
        $newsurvey = $copy->replicate();

        // save
        $newsurvey->save();
}
```

So, I expect it copies the selected one. But it only copies that data. It doesn't copy another related tables

Model with relations:

```
 public function accuracy() {

    return $this->hasOne( 'App\Models\LimeSurvey\Accuracy', 'survey_id', 'sid' );
}

public function groups() {

    return $this->hasMany( 'App\Models\LimeSurvey\Group', 'sid', 'sid' )->orderBy('gid', 'asc')->orderBy('group_order', 'asc');
}

public function questions() {

    return $this->hasMany( 'App\Models\LimeSurvey\Question', 'sid', 'sid' )->orderBy('gid', 'asc')->orderBy('question_order', 'asc');
}

public function parentQuestions() {

    return $this->hasMany( 'App\Models\LimeSurvey\Question', 'sid', 'sid' )->where('parent_qid', '=', 0)->orderBy('gid', 'asc')->orderBy('question_order', 'asc');
}

public function languages() {

    return $this->hasMany( 'App\Models\LimeSurvey\Language', 'surveyls_survey_id', 'sid' );
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, do you mean that you `replicate()` doesn't include related tables? - if so, show us your model aswell.

Comment: `replicate` won't replicate many-to-many relationship entries in the pivot automatically. You will need to manually, if that is what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do it manually,

Try this code:

```
public function copySurvey( Manager $fractal, SurveyTransformer $surveyTransformer ) {
    $copy = Survey::first();

    //copy attributes
    $newsurvey = $copy->replicate();

    foreach($copy->languages() as $language)
    {
        $newsurvey->languages()->attach($language);
    }

    foreach($copy->parentQuestions() as $question)
    {
        $newsurvey->parentQuestions()->attach($question);
    }

    foreach($copy->accuracy() as $acc)
    {
        $newsurvey->accuracy()->attach($acc);
    }

    foreach($copy->questions() as $question)
    {
        $newsurvey->questions()->attach($question);
    }

    foreach($copy->groups() as $group)
    {
        $newsurvey->groups()->attach($group);
    }

    // save
    $newsurvey->save();
}
```

This assumes your relation accessors are `groups(), permissions(), questions()`

Comment: it calls undifned method permissions? so i need to define that somewhere

Comment: @PatrickStek Yes, this suggests you didn't define relations at all. Show us the model in your main post.

Comment: Done for you. this is de Survey model

Comment: Thanks. But he dindt work. He only Copy the selected one. So i have one survey and i need to copy all data from this survey. But when i click on copy now he only copy the name. But he needs to copy the questions and all of that data from that survey what i selected.. ":(